# Conditional inside loop on an xml PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have an xml like this. There are items with old price and some dont have.

```
<product>
    <item>
        <name>product 1</name>
        <price type="old">100</price>
        <price type="new">50</price>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>product 2</name>
        <price type="old">100</price>
        <price type="new">50</price>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>product 3</name>
        <price type="new">50</price>
    </item>
</product>
```

I want to iterate through each item but only get those that have type="old" items.

Comment: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples.php

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use xpath to fetch the items directly:

Get all `item` children inside the `product` document element

`/product/item`

that have a `price` child element

`/product/item[price]`

where the attribute `type` has the value `old`

`/product/item[price[@type="old"]]`

Example: https://eval.in/106865

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$items = $xpath->evaluate('/product/item[price[@type="old"]]');
foreach ($items as $item) {
  var_dump(
    $xpath->evaluate('string(name)', $item)
  ); 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `xpath`

```
$xml = new SimpleXmlElement($str);
$result = $xml->xpath('/product/item');
$items = array();
foreach($result as $res){
  $price = $res->xpath('price');
  foreach($price as $p){
   if($p['type']=='old'){
     $items[] = $res;
   }
  }
}
```

See demo [here](https://eval.in/106761)